# JavaFX8 - How to draw random circles with random x/y centers?

Tags: javafx-8

I am trying to draw random circles with random x/y centers, but the result of my code is only one circle at the center of the stage (window).

I use Task class to update my UI every 1 second.

This is my code:

```
package javafxupdateui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXUpdateUI extends Application {

    private Stage window;
    private StackPane layout;
    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("JavaFX - Update UI");

        layout = new StackPane();
        scene = new Scene(layout, 500, 500);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();
    }

    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            while (true) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            drawCircles();
                    }
                });

                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    };

    public void drawCircles() {
        Circle circle;
        float x = (float)(Math.random()*501);
        float y = (float)(Math.random()*501);
        circle = new Circle(x, y, 25, Color.RED);
        layout.getChildren().add(circle);
        scene.setRoot(layout);
        window.setScene(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The result of the above code is:
[Result GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jjba.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What is going wrong*

[StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) is a layout pane, it centers everything by default.  As you want to manually place the circles at random locations, you don't want to use a pane which manages the layout for you.

*How to fix it*

Use a [Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) or a [Group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) instead of StackPane.  Neither Pane nor Group manage the layout of items for you, so children you add to them at specific locations will remain at those locations.

*Aside*

You might wish to use a [Timeline for your periodic updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task) rather than a Task with runLater (though the later will still work OK, with a Timeline you don't have to deal with additional complexities of concurrent code).